# URL parsing error with Arabic text

Tags: ios, json, swift, arabic

I am trying to translate Arabic to English using a web service. I get an error when constructing the URL. I've defined these cases:

```
enum MyErrors: Error {
    case urlParsingError(String)
    case nonDictonaryObjectReturned(Any)
}
```

And my code is:

```
func translateWord (text: String, ToLan:String) {

   // the text is "مرحبا" and ToLan is "en"

    do {
        let jsonString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=apikey&text=\(text)&lang=\(ToLan)"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else {
            throw MyErrors.urlParsingError(jsonString)
        }

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: Data.ReadingOptions())

        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,options: .allowFragments)
        guard let dictionary = jsonObject as? [AnyHashable: Any] else {
            throw MyErrors.nonDictonaryObjectReturned(jsonObject)
        }
        let result = dictionary["text"] as? [Any]
        let translattedSTR = result?.first as? String
        let encodedData = translattedSTR?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        print(encodedData!)
        self.textresult.text = translattedSTR


    } catch {
        print("caught error \(error)")
    }
```

but unfortunately, it prints

> caught error urlParsingError(output url)

also, my the structure looks something like [this](https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key= apikey&text=مرحبا&lang=en)

Comment: Im not fluent in arabic or how to use it on the web, but are you sure that `"مرحبا"` is being translated properly into utf8? i'm guessing that's probably what's happening. However, I wouldn't know how arabic characters/words are transposed into their visual form (`"مرحبا"`) from http formats :/

Comment: try printing out the url before the guard statement

Comment: @murphguy, i am not an arab too, i don't speak arabic, but this is for a project, i guess that it's because of "مرحباا", it works fine on the browser, but not in xcode

Comment: Perhaps, have you added Arabic as a language to your project through Internationalisation steps? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar I hope that API key is not your real production key, since you just posted it on a public page. If it was your real production key, I suggest you immediately change it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, oh no it's not, but i changed it

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar Anyone can look at the edits to the question and answers so removing the key in an edit doesn't really hide it.

Comment: thank you guys, seems like i can't remove the question, what should i do?

Comment: You said it's not your real production key so don't worry about it. But if it really is, get a new one.

Comment: @rmaddy, alright, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to properly encode the values of the query parameters. One good solution is to use `URLComponents` to build your query.

Then these lines:

```
let jsonString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=myAPIkey&text=\(text)&lang=\(ToLan)"

guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else {
    throw MyErrors.urlParsingError(jsonString)
}
```

need to be replaced with:

```
let baseString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate"
var comps = URLComponents(string: baseString)!
let keyQuery = URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: "myAPIKey")
let textQuery = URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: text)
let langQuery = URLQueryItem(name: "lang", value: ToLan)
comps.queryItems = [ keyQuery, textQuery, langQuery ]
guard let url = comps.url else {
    throw MyErrors.urlParsingError("\(comps)")
}
```

The resulting url is now:

> https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=myAPIkey&text=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7&lang=en

Comment: I prefer this solution to the `addingPercentEncoding` solution because different parts of the URL have different encoding requirements.

Comment: thank you so much @rmaddy, god bless you, saved dozens of hours

Comment: It seems that your last edit introduced some errors, it does not compile anymore. – Note that if `comps.url` is nil then `comps.string` might be nil as well, so you cannot use `comps.string!` in the error message.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing out my last bad edit. Fixed. You may be right about accessing the `string` property but I ran a few tests and I couldn't get the guard to fail. Anything I did to make a bad URL caused `URLComponents(string: baseString)!` to crash. Anything done to the query items were properly escaped.

Comment: Try `var comps = URLComponents(string: "https://foo.com")!; comps.path = "path/without/leading/slash"`

Comment: @MartinR I didn't consider `path` since it wasn't needed here but that demonstrates the issue. It seems the easiest is to pass the description of `comps`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode your String to get a valid URL. You can do this by using `String.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: )`.

```
let jsonString = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170517T154730Z.927d87b76de60242.7a92e4612778a4838d40ab192df5297d2a1af4ed&text=\(text)&lang=\(ToLan)"

guard let encodedJsonString = jsonString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: encodedJsonString) else {
    throw MyErrors.urlParsingError(jsonString)
}
```

The encoded URL becomes:

> https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170517T154730Z.927d87b76de60242.7a92e4612778a4838d40ab192df5297d2a1af4ed&text=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7&lang=en

Comment: thank you, both of the answers work, i'll give my upvote